# screen and view coordinates in Android

Tags: android, view, draw

If user touchs the screen I can get coordinates of this touch by using methods of MotionEvent getX() and getY().

But if I understood it right for drawing of canvas other coordinates will be used.

My colleague meant, these are view and screen coordinates. But he didn't know, if there are some transformations methods.

Maybe you can help me.

Thank you in advance,

Mur

**UPD**

I've got a bit confusion. I'm using osmdroid, they are drawing overlays as canvas.

So if I'm comparing canvas coordinates they are using for drawing with MotionEvent coordinates I don't understand anything.

These are coordinates of rectangle (left, right, bottom, top) 16899.0 / 16948.0 -86483.0 / -86515.0 I've printed out.

Coordinates of MotionEvent are 252.0 / 223.0

Answer (score 1):

He is wrong.  Canvas doesn't use anything different.  You just have to consider where the canvas is located on the screen in relation to where the user touched.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw at location 0,0 on your canvas you will draw in the top left corner. So you don't have to do anything special.

Perhaps your friend has got a bit confused with screen/window locations: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow(int[])

Answer (score 0):

> These are coordinates of rectangle (left, right, bottom, top) 16899.0 / 16948.0 -86483.0 / -86515.0 I've printed out.
>
> Coordinates of MotionEvent are 0/0 to 252 / 223

Looks like osmdroid is trasforming coordinates. This makes sense for a map, so if you draw something at 0,0 you will draw something at your location.

I suppose returning coordinates are map coordinates, starting from location (0,0) because an image 16899.0+86483.0=103382.0 pixel tall and 16948.0+86515.0=103463.0 pixel wide is an image of 10200 gigapixel, consuming almost 30 Tb of memory, and I am in doubt that a smarphone can have such a lot of memory free...

So for your app I suggest an approach like this:

```
touch = touch coordinates
scale = map scale
top = top left of the map

point_on_map = top + (touch*scale)
```